# OpenShift, JBoss EAP 6 - how to re-add MySQL driver

Tags: mysql, openshift, jboss-eap-6

I have a Java EE 6 application on OpenShift / JBoss EAP 6, which runs out of space regularly due to big server logs.

Recently, the EAP got broken somehow. It can't find the MySQL driver anymore.
The driver is installed when adding the MySQL cartridge (`rhc cartridge add mysql-5.1 -a MyApp`).
Restarting everything doesn't help.
Deleting the MySQL cartridge and adding it again doesn't help.

- Is there a way to add the EAP module without dropping the database?
- Why the deployment-scanner subsystem is not found?

This is the related config on OpenShift (standard)

```
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
                    <deployment-scanner path="deployments"
                            relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"
                            deployment-timeout="300" />
            </subsystem>
```

```
2013/08/31 21:03:09,044 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 
  (management-handler-thread - 4) JBAS014613: Operation ("read-resource") failed
  - address:  ([("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner")]) 
  - failure description: "JBAS014807: Management resource 
    '[(\"subsystem\" => \"deployment-scanner\")]' not found"
2013/08/31 21:03:09,224 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: ROOT.war
2013/08/31 21:03:09,888 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900 1.1.8 (redhat)
2013/08/31 21:03:10,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader
2013/08/31 21:03:10,881 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS018559: Deployed "ROOT.war"
2013/08/31 21:03:10,887 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing) dependents: 
      [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS] 

2013/08/31 21:03:11,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.8.207.1:9990
2013/08/31 21:03:11,079 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started (with errors) in 33174ms - Started 240 of 412 services (38 services failed or missing dependencies, 131 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved. The JDBC driver module has to be in git repo under `.openshift/config/modules/`. It wasn't there before and the web worked, so I wonder if something changed in OpenShift.

.openshift/config/modules/com/mysql/jdbc/main/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar

And

.openshift/config/modules/com/mysql/jdbc/main/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql.jdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```